# How do I turn a sanity io document field that is an array of objects to an array of strings

Tags: arrays, object, sanity

I have a recipes.js document that has a tag field:

```
    {
      name: 'tags',
      title: 'Tags',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'reference', to: { type: 'tags' } }],
      options: {
        layout: 'tags',
      },
    },
```

it references another document called tags.js:

```
export default {
  name: 'tags',
  type: 'document',
  title: 'Tags',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'title',
      title: 'Title',
      type: 'string',
    },
  ],
};
```

I am trying to add the tags to each recipe as an array of strings in graphql. such as:

```
"tags": ['dinner', 'lunch', 'ribs']
```

but instead, I get an array of objects:

```
          "tags": [
            {
              "title": "breakfast"
            },
            {
              "title": "pancakes"
            },
            {
              "title": "food"
            }
          ]
```

How can I tell sanity all I want is each one to be added in as a string so it is an array of strings and not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanity's GraphQL API does not support transforming the data structure into something else. If you want to do that, you will have to use [GROQ](https://www.sanity.io/docs/overview-groq).

Comment: Thanks! i was able to loob over the objects and me the array. I will learn GROQ for future projects,